# All occurrences of "\section\subsection..." in the template all report the following error "Undefined control sequence. \section{Introduction}"

Tags: latex3

This is the template download link I use. [Template download link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RkTVWI8srMZzkb1-Ma1gTRxA8vtP9oF6/view?usp=sharing)   When I uncomment the "\section" in the template, some errors will be reported.

```
\documentclass[jcs]{iosart2x}

\pubyear{0000}
\volume{0}
\firstpage{1}
\lastpage{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

%\pretitle{}
\title{Article Title}
\runningtitle{Article Title}
%\subtitle{}

% Two or more authors:
\author[A]{\inits{N.}\fnms{Name1} \snm{Surname1}\ead[label=e1]{first@somewhere.com}%
\thanks{Corresponding author. \printead{e1}.}},
\author[B]{\inits{N.N.}\fnms{Name2 Name2} \snm{Surname2}\ead[label=e2]{second@somewhere.com}}
and
\author[B]{\inits{N.-N.}\fnms{Name3-Name3} \snm{Surname3}\ead[label=e3]{third@somewhere.com}}
\runningauthor{N. Surname1 et al.}
\address[A]{Department first, \orgname{University or Company name},
Abbreviate US states, \cny{Country}\printead[presep={\\}]{e1}}
\address[B]{Department first, \orgname{University or Company name},
Abbreviate US states, \cny{Country}\printead[presep={\\}]{e2,e3}}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract text.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\kwd{Keyword one}
\kwd{keyword two}
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{}\label{s1}

\subsection{}\label{s1.1}
```

The error message is as follows：

```
Undefined control sequence. \section{}
Undefined control sequence. \subsection{}
Undefined control sequence. \begin{thebibliography}{5}
Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{thebibliography}{5}
```

log information:

```
\c@sv@footnote=\count309
! Undefined control sequence.
\Sectionformat #1#2->\ios@Sectionformat 
                                        {#1\@nameuse {ios@section@level@\ios...
l.60 \section{}
               \label{s1}
```

Comment: Your link doesn't work. Please show a MWE code in your question.

Comment: Even if it did work, I'm not inclined to download a random zip file.

Comment: I re-edited the link and it is ready to download.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Plwasw show as an example  of small document, which reproduce your problem,

Comment: ok. I have re-edited the question.

Comment: Please help me! thank you all!